# destroy an entity after a time limit in marty engine +slick

Tags: game-engine, slick2d

Is there a way to destroy an entity after a predefined time limit exceeds.? I want to destroy a ship when it's lifetime(measured in seconds) exceeds. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found something, the delta value we get as a parameter in update method is the time (in miliseconds) passed since the last call to update method. so we can keep adding it to a variable until the life limit reach.